# Could you anybody see my code & say any alternative for %s in integer?

Tags: java

How %s is work for int ??

```
   package loops;

    public class Checking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String formatter = "hello";
        int formatter1 = 2;
        System.out.printf("%s friend %n",formatter);
        System.out.printf("%s cup of coffee please",formatter1);
        /* problem is
        %s stands for string
        How %s is work for integer in formatter 1 (System.out.printf("%s cup of coffee please",formatter1);
        "i am beginner in java,
        */
    }
    }
```

Output is correct

But I want to know is there alternative for integer?

Comment: The symbol for integral numbers is `%d` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)). And `%s` works for `int` by simply calling `Integer.toString`.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ Please see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why are you using `%s` to begin with? The documentation can be important to understand what is happening: [Format string syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger  I like to use that....is cause any problem in error ?? [i m beginner in java]

Comment: I do not think it is a problem, but "like to use" is kind of a strange *programming technique* ... cause of problem could be not knowing what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol for integral numbers is `%d` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)). And `%s` works for int by simply calling `Integer.toString`.

From the Doc:

`'s', 'S'  If`arg`implements`Formattable`, then`arg.formatTo`is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking`arg.toString()`.`

So, when you pass an `int` is is autoboxed to `Integer` and on that `Integer` the method `.toString` is called, so your `int` becomes a `String`.

In general I recommend to read the manual, especially if you are a novice programmer. A lot of wisdom from the authors is distilled into the docs.